# Why don't work custom validator (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular4-forms

I have the situation when I need check equal two fields in the registration form. It's inputs password and repeat password. And I create my validator for this task. But for equal two string checking, I need to get `form` object in my validator:

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  private formSubmitAttempt: boolean; 
  form: FormGroup;                   

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,        
              private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({     // {5}
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      dpassword: ['', [Validators.required, this.validateMatchPasswords.bind(this)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    });
  }

  validateMatchPasswords(control: FormControl) {
    const err = this.form.get('password').value === this.form.get('dpassword').value;
    return {
      error: false
    };
  }

  onSubmit() {
    ...
  }
}
```

`validateMatchPasswords` - my validator method, but it generates the 
 ERROR:

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at RegistrationComponent.validateMatchPasswords (registration.component.ts:32)
    at eval (forms.js:759)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:759)
    at FormControl.eval [as validator] (forms.js:711)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.js:3433)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3387)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:3905)
    at FormBuilder.control (forms.js:7899)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:7965)
```

And `form` object doesn't available in `validateMatchPasswords` method despite the fact that I bind `this` in `ngOnInit()` -`this.validateMatchPasswords.bind(this)`

Why I get this Error^ and how to fix this issue? thank You!

I use `angular.material` to build my components:

```
<div class="signin-content">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        ...
        <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">
          <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Create new password"
                 formControlName="password" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('password')">
            Please inform your password. Minimum 5 symbol.
          </mat-error>
        </mat-input-container>

        <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">
          <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Repeat you're password"
                 formControlName="dpassword" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('dpassword')">
            Passwords do not match
          </mat-error>
        </mat-input-container>
        ...
      </form>    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create fiddler/codepen of your code?

Comment: @VicJordan sorry don't understand. What do you mean for fiddler/codepen?

Comment: create `executable code snippet` of your code

Answer (score 0):

Create a form group and add a validator on that group. Here is an example that is untested, however it should work (I've used this approach before in the past).

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = fb.group({
            email: [null, Validators.email],
            passwords: fb.group({
                password: [null, Validators.required],
                passwordConfirmation: [null, Validators.required]
            }, {validator: this.shouldMatchValidator('password', 'passwordConfirmation')
        });
    }

    shouldMatchValidator(...props: string[]) {
        return (group: FormGroup): any => shouldMatch(group, ...props);
    }

    shouldMatch(group: FormGroup, ...props: string[]): any {
        const ctrls = group.controls;
        const len = props.length;

        for (let i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            if (ctrls[props[0]]) {
                if (ctrls[props[0]].value !== ctrls[props[i]].value) {
                    return {invalid: true};
                }
            } else {
                throw new Error(`The property '${props[0]}' passed to 'shouldMatch()' was not found on the form group.`);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```